# Cannot initialize effect engine

Tags: java, android, kotlin, session, audio

When calling the setEqualizerData() method, namely when initializing myEq = Equalizer(0, musicPlayingId), an error occurs: Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3

```
private fun setEqualizerData() {
myEq = Equalizer(0, musicPlayingId) //Error //musicPlayingId = 0
myEq!!.enabled = true
setBoost(sharedPreferences.getFloat(LOUDER_LEVEL, 1f))
myEq!!.setBandLevel(
    0,
    sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_1_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
)
myEq!!.setBandLevel(
    1,
    sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_2_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
)
myEq!!.setBandLevel(
    2,
    sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_3_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
)
myEq!!.setBandLevel(
    3,
    sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_4_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
)
myEq!!.setBandLevel(
    4,
    sharedPreferences.getInt(BAND_5_LEVEL, 1500).toShort()
)
mBassBoost = BassBoost(0, musicPlayingId)
mBassBoost!!.enabled = true
setBassBoost()
virtualizer = Virtualizer(0, musicPlayingId)
virtualizer!!.enabled = true
setVirtualizer()
loudness = LoudnessEnhancer(musicPlayingId)
```

}

stacktrace:

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3
   at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.<init>(AudioEffect.java:468)
   at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>(Equalizer.java:139)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.setEqualizerData(MainActivity.kt:343)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.setDataToView(MainActivity.kt:529)
   at example.androidvolumelouder.presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:147)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Help please, what's the problem?

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75046535/edit) your question to include where `musicPlayingId` came from.

Comment: musicPlayingId it ID audio session

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939711/295004 and show code of how it was assigned.

Comment: I need a global audio session id. How to get it?  Does it default to 0?